# Deleting a complete line if an entry in the line is not present a list

Tags: python

I am trying to parse every line in `list.txt` and if any of the change(number) is not present in `change_list`, delete that whole entry (not just that number) and create an new file `OUTPUT.txt` with the remaining numbers.

In the below example 350166 is not present in `change_list`, so the whole line "350882 348521 350166" is removed and only the remaining ones are added to `output.txt`.

For some reason I dont seem to get the desired outupt. Can anyone point where is it going wrong?

```
change_list=[]
def changecheck(change) :
    changelist=['355199','352470','346917','350882','348521']
    if change in changelist:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f :
        line=line.strip()
        change_line = line
    print "change_line"
    print change_line

for element in change_line:
    change_list = element.split(' ')
    for changeid in change_list:
        print "changeid"
        print changeid
        returnVal = changecheck('changeId')
        if returnVal  == 1:
            #write the whole line to a new file
            with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
                f.writelines(element)
```

files:

```
list.txt
350882 348521 350166
346917 352470 
355199 

OUTPUT.txt
346917 352470 
355199
```

Comment: you don't need to use 1 and 0. you can simply use `if change in changelist: with open...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `changecheck` a `set`, and then build a generator over the input splitting it up into separate numbers, and only include lines in the file where all numbers on the line are in the changecheck..., eg:

```
changelist = {'355199','352470','346917','350882','348521'}

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    lines = (line.split() for line in fin)
    valid = (' '.join(line) + '\n' for line in lines if all(el in changelist for el in line))
    fout.writelines(valid)
```

Comment: I think the main missed point in the question is the `'w'` flag.